# Sealing cut branches with regular spray paint

Tags: trees

I need to prune a red oak tree in August in Iowa. Can I use regular spray paint to seal the cut off branches?

Comment: could you explain "the make" of Spray paint you intend to use? active chemicals or where you got it from- from my experience most trees don't need seal off paints although many years ago people did  use something called chesnut compound which is a tar based paint with fungicide added- but todays advice is don't use anything if your not sure.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely not!

First, the use of any kind of sealant on pruned trees is, as a rule of thumb, no longer recommended at all. [Research](https://cals.arizona.edu/yavapai/anr/hort/byg/archive/pruningsealants.html) shows that they can actually *hinder* proper healing of the wounds. Working with clean tools, cutting the right way and at the right time should be enough.

Second, you are falling into the trap of the English language's tendency to simplify things. While the wound sealant is sometimes labeled as "pruning *paint*", it's by no means a "paint", but typically a waxy or rubbery smear or paste.

So no, you can not use spray paint. Learn about how to prune your tree, clean your tools before the job, then *leave the cuts alone*.